# How to Send an email by using custom button based on some criteria?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, custom-object, custom-button

We have created a javascript based button.. As **javascript buttons are not supported by lightning** we need to look for any other solution. Thinking about VF and lightning. please suggest

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 
var Suite = '{!Contract_Extract__c.Suite__c}'; 
var check = '{!Contract_Extract__c.Leadership_Notification_check__c}'; 
var TOV = '{!Contract_Extract__c.TOV__c}'; 
var RedLightReview = '{!Contract_Extract__c.Red_Light_Review__c}'; 
var ce = new sforce.SObject("Contract_Extract__C"); 
ce.id = "{!Contract_Extract__c.Id}"; 
if (( TOV >= 5000000000 || Suite != ' ' || RedLightReview != ' ' ) && check==0)
{ 
ce.Leadership_Notification_check__c = 1; 
result = sforce.connection.update([ce]); 
}
```

**we need to convert this code to work in both lex and classic** ....

Please try to give suggestions ASAP on this

Answer (score 1):

Try something similar to the below code Add you criteria inside the Send () method

```
  //Vf page
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="SendEmailPageController">
<apex:form >
    <apex:commandButton action="{!send}"  value="Send Email" />
    <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" />
</apex:form>
</apex:page>


//Controller

public class SendEmailPageController
{
public SendEmailPageController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{
}
public PageReference send()
{
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'abc@yahoo.com'};
    mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
    mail.setBccSender(false);
    mail.setSubject('Subject');
    mail.setPlainTextBody('Test Message Body');
    Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail});
    for ( Messaging.SendEmailResult result : r )
    {
        if ( !r[0].isSuccess () )
        {
            System.debug ( result  );
        }
        else
        {
            ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'Email Sent Successfully' );
            ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
        }
    }
    return null;

}
}
```

Comment: few things also i need like add multiple email ids from custom field in CC and instead of plaintext we need to use the existing vf email template. If possible can you please help me with these  as well...changes in the given code appreciated.

Comment: @Reddy you can use this script mail.setTemplateId('00X30000001GLJj');
 to set a specific template to send email and for multiple recipient  "mail.setToAddresses(new String[] { 'TestUser@salesforce.com' ,'abc@test.com'});" you can try this

Comment: We don't want to hardcode the email ids. We need to pick the email ids that has been populated in the custom field.

Comment: @Reddy then its simple just refer the Custom field name in place of the hardcoded Id's.

Comment: String[] toAddresses = new String[] {CsEmail};
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);

Comment: As you mensioned, I have tried adding the template but receiving empty email. any idea?

Comment: @Reddy can you update your question with what you have tried

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55811/discussion-between-reddy-and-samuel-robert).

Answer (score 0):

If you need a button for both environments, try to do a JS button for classic and a Lightning Component with [Lightning Quick Action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_component_actions.htm) interface for Lightning Experience & Salesforce1.

Create a Lightning component to display some info with a lightning:button that executes a Controller method that sends an email.

Comment: what if i use vf page only for both classic and lex?